# How to identify whether a metal carbonate is basic or not?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

Magnesium carbonate is basic, but why isn't lithium carbonate also basic? And how does one determine whether a carbonate is basic or not?

Comment: Who says lithium carbonate is not basic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lithium carbonate and magnesium carbonate behave near enough the same. lithium carbonate is basic just not as basic as other group 1 carbonates. It also has low solubility in water and is the only group 1 carbonate that isn't thermally stable.

It is still is basic but it just doesn't fit to the general trends.